# How do I check if two balls collide in tkinter?

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter

Working on a small project involving tkinter and I need to figure out how to get balls bouncing off of each other.

Heres the code:

```
from tkinter import *

# dimensions of canvas
WIDTH=300
HEIGHT=400

# Create window and canvas
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='#ADF6BE')
canvas.pack()

# starting position of ball
x = 0
y = 10
# starting position of ball1
x1 = 100
y1 = 0

# distance moved each time step for ball 1
dx = 10
dy= 10
# distance moved each time step for ball 2
dx1 = 10
dy1 = 10

# diameter of ball
ballsize = 30


while True:
   x = x + dx
   y = y + dy
   x1 = x1 + dx1
   y1 = y1 + dy1

   # if ball get to edge then we need to
   # change direction of movement
   if x >= WIDTH-ballsize or x <= 0 or x == x1:
      dx = -dx
      print("x=", x)
      print('y=', y)
   if y >= HEIGHT-ballsize or y <= 0 or y == y1:
      dy = -dy
      print("x=", x)
      print('y=', y)

   if x1 >= WIDTH-ballsize or x1 <= 0 or x1 == x:
      dx1 = -dx1
      print("x1=", x1)
      print('y1=', y1)
   if y1 >= HEIGHT-ballsize or y1 <= 0 or y1 == y:
      dy1 = -dy1
      print("x1=", x1)
      print('y1=', y1)


   # Create balls
   ball=canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+ballsize, y+ballsize, fill="white", outline='white')
   ball1 = canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x1 + ballsize, y1 + ballsize, fill="white", outline='white')
   # display ball
   canvas.update()
   canvas.after(50)
   #remove ball
   canvas.delete(ball)
   canvas.delete(ball1)

window.mainloop()
```

They move and bounce off of the canvas walls but not off of each other.

Heres an image to show what I mean, instead of hitting each other and bouncing off

[image: Balls not colliding]

Comment: I see your code for detecting walls, but don't see anything to detect other balls. Just add that in the same place. I'd also recommend you update the ball position instead or deleting and remaking the balls for every frame (that will help it run more smoothly).

Comment: Calculate the `distance` between the centers of the two balls, if `distance <= ballsize`, then the two balls collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the distance between the balls.
If the distance between the center of the two circles is less than the sum of the radii of the circles, then they are colliding.

`(math.sqrt((ball1.x- ball2.x) ** 2 + (ball1.y - ball2.y) ** 2) <= sum_radii`

Then change the dy and dx of the balls.

Comment: It should be the *diameter* (assume the two balls have same radius), not radius.

Comment: You have to check if the _distance_ between the center of the two circles is less than the _sum of the radii_ of the circles. This is for a general case. If the circles have same radius then you can use the diameter. I will edit my answer to be more clear.